# ruby install fail using brew, error C compiler can not create excutables

Tags: macos, install, xcode, homebrew

I am trying to install something using brew, but I get the following error, c compiler is unable to create an executable. I installed Xcode and the command line tools.

```
Drs-MBP-2:Qt5.14.2 sherif_omran$ brew install rbenv ruby-build 
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/cask and homebrew/core).
==> New Formulae
nerdctl
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 42 formulae.
==> Renamed Formulae
mr2 -> zoro
==> Updated Casks
Updated 9 casks.
==> Deleted Casks
jalbum

Warning: You are using macOS 10.13.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.

==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/m4/m4-1.4.19.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/sherif_omran/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/1b3275d8fa55c27c48d0dc1ea0d6f1e05308bb826e4f1df51c026b08f28a37a3--m4-1.4.19.tar.xz
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.71.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/sherif_omran/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/70e2744f2b485424b5ad79ac600895f02258d01f5a8425994c340e1d013a7216--autoconf-2.71.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/pkg-config/manifests/0.29.2_3
Already downloaded: /Users/sherif_omran/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/ac691fc7ab8ecffba32a837e7197101d271474a3a84cfddcc30c9fd6763ab3c6--pkg-config-0.29.2_3.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/pkg-config/blobs/sha256:8c6160305abd948b8cf3e0d5c6bb0df192fa765bbb9535dda0b573cb60abbe52
Already downloaded: /Users/sherif_omran/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/506df5e0002bc557fe9c6a6eadce3e4bbe4ecdfd029053bdc950d6569c9e40bc--pkg-config--0.29.2_3.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-8.1-patches/readline81-001
Already downloaded: /Users/sherif_omran/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/6607f4de8f3c741c80b9d2b64e03b93056bec46d0534dafc9d8f714c95debea7--readline81-001
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-8.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/sherif_omran/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/118fcba9dbeb2dd253f11507b4f4e3167af70954a464b35e4d0d7e79d3965d1b--readline-8.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/ruby-build/manifests/20211227
Already downloaded: /Users/sherif_omran/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/0f1027210e3670dfc5327204a123502e9d6176d439c4909353ec4f4a2a95864c--ruby-build-20211227.bottle_manifest.json
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/ruby-build/blobs/sha256:3d18d498a34fca3e657a14614e88d87f114a8fd3d419596a6f986f42fe034be5
Already downloaded: /Users/sherif_omran/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/44be296c211777a5567387cffbb54cc3cecfe1613afddf7ebb2cebb01b292cb4--ruby-build--20211227.all.bottle.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/archive/v1.2.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/sherif_omran/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/04b752d33f8d66d3c8185a7780267cd2ccef6f82b194186d809c805b5ae4f33b--rbenv-1.2.0.tar.gz
==> Installing dependencies for rbenv: m4, autoconf, pkg-config, readline and ruby-build
==> Installing rbenv dependency: m4
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/m4/1.4.19
Last 15 lines from /Users/sherif_omran/Library/Logs/Homebrew/m4/01.configure:
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a race-free mkdir -p... ./build-aux/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/m4-20220101-94670-1hbcfr6/m4-1.4.19':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


Error: You are using macOS 10.13.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.

Drs-MBP-2:Qt5.14.2 sherif_omran$ gcc
clang: error: no input files
Drs-MBP-2:Qt5.14.2 sherif_omran$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
Drs-MBP-2:Qt5.14.2 sherif_omran$
```

Update:

I could solve it using manual installation of CLANG compiler using ports. Brew kept asking for compiler to compile the code, but ports let me install the compiler package.

Comment: Did you look at config.log as the message says?

Comment: here is config.log, https://pastebin.com/T7BvjnXn

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say, `ports let me install the compiler package`, does that mean that MacPorts let you install the compiler?

Comment: @Seamus: yes macports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but the issue seems to be stated clearly:

> Error: You are using macOS 10.13.
> We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.

I don't use Homebrew because of *philosophical differences* :)  I use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) instead. I just checked, and they do support High Sierra (10.13) & even much *"older"* versions (Tiger/10.4) that may be [downloaded here](https://www.macports.org/install.php#installing). MacPorts also maintains a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/macports) where you may find other *useful stuff*, post issues, etc.

Most helpfully, MacPorts provides [installation instructions](https://www.macports.org/install.php) for both Macports and Xcode for all supported versions. Apple still sources vintage versions of Xcode and the "Command Line Tools" on their [Developer's Site](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/).

Comment: macports supports back to Tiger - although many apps can't be ported as they use new things

Comment: It also helps to use the macports home page where the install instructions  https://www.macports.org/install.php tell you how to install both Xcode and Macports on all versions back to Tiger

Comment: @mmmmmm: Thank you for that information. I've tried to incorporate it into my answer, but please suggest any edits you feel might be an improvement.

Comment: yes i could solve it using port and installing the llvc compiler clang and manual adjustment of the compiler.

Comment: @Dr.SherifOmran I think you and Seamus are getting confused. If you use macports you do not need to manually adjust the compiler. Macports does that all for you e.g. just install macports (and Xcode command line tools  and then `sudo port install rbenv` No need for Homebrew ata all or any other setup

Comment: @Seamus Much much better to remove all reference to Github for macports it makes things much more complex then their home page.

Comment: @mmmmmm: I don't think *I'm* confused on the compiler point, but it's certainly worth a comment :)